# unit test cases visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I am new to unit-tests. I am about to start working on a big project using C#, VS2010. I was wondering if its a good idea to use test-framework that comes with VS2010, or should I look for third party frameworks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reset of the organization you're in is using MSTest, that's a good reason to use it.  If you are doing this on your own, that reasoning is irrelevant.

For third-party frameworks, nUnit works well with VS2010, and it's easy to find information on how to use it.  It's the only one I've used, since my previous employer didn't pony up for the MS Test licensing.

The key to using unit test frameworks is learning how to write good tests, not necessarily what tool you use.

For a good overview that uses .NET, I'd recommend Roy Osherove's book, http://www.manning.com/osherove/

Good luck!

Comment: if you consider this a reasonable answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to mark an answer... do you know how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask  This should show you how to click the big check box underneat the big number with the arrows above and below to accept an answer.  As the person who asked the question, you should be able to click that.